# Can't read txt file from sdcard AVD emulator Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to read a file from sd but I can't.
This is my code.

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

My class for read file:

```
public ParsingFromTxt(String nomeFile, ArrayList<Squadra> squadre) throws IOException
{
    //Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
    //*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Get the text file
    File file = new File(sdcard, "07-01.txt");
    if(file.exists())
        Log.d("log", "esiste");
    Log.d("log", file.getAbsolutePath());
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        Log.d("log", br.readLine());
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        { ...
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
         Log.d("log", "errore"); 
    }
```

This is what I read in the console:

```
11-05 16:32:25.980 2144-2144/prova.myapplication D/log: esiste
11-05 16:32:25.980 2144-2144/prova.myapplication D/log: /storage/12EA-101E/07-01.txt
11-05 16:32:25.980 2144-2144/prova.myapplication D/log: Errore
```

Help me to find the error.

Comment: put a exc.printStackTrace() line inside your catch block and post the output

Comment: i have this error
EACCESS permission denied. When i read with ls -l the permission with a adb shell i read that the file is property of root...This is the problem?

Comment: Yes, thats your problem.

Comment: what's the solution. How can i allow my application to open a file that is property of another user/group?

Comment: You can root your device and give your app root permissions. there is no other way to access root files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add one more permission to manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: I inserted your line in my manifest file but I can't read file text again

Comment: i read this from adb shell:

root@generic_x86_64:/sdcard # ls -l
-rwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw     5485 2015-10-16 10:04 07-01.txt

Now i'm trying to execute chmod 777 07-01.txt but it can't change the permission of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work on a real device?

Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?